# Querying multiple tables on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been studying MySQL through a book called '**PHP and MySQL Web Development**' and I'm on a chapter that teaches how to query data from multiple tables, I was trying to do it on my own and came up with the following command

```
mysql> select customers.name from books, customers, orders, orders_items
    -> where books.title = 'Java 2'
    -> and books.isbn = orders_items.isbn
    -> and orders_items.orderid = orders.orderid
    -> and orders.customersid = customers.customerid;
```

and it returns me the following error

```
    ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'books.orders_items' doesn't exist
```

but when I try to use the command exactly as it is in the book it works just fine

```
mysql>select customers.name from customers, orders, order_items, books
    ->where customers.customerid = orders.customerid
    ->and orders.orderid = order_items.orderid
    ->and order_items.isbn = books.isbn
    ->and books.title = 'Java 2';

+-------------+
| name        |
+-------------+
| Julie Smith |
+-------------+
```

What am I missing here besides the order of the criteria?
I have not typed *books.orders_items* anywhere.

Comment: can you describe / show the table schemas involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the plural `orders_items` not the singular from the book `order_items`

both here

> select customers.name from books, customers, orders, **orders_items**

and in line

> and books.isbn = **orders_items**.isbn

Comment: Boy dont I feel pretty dumb right now? lol I was thinking that the error was a column inside a table, but its a table inside a database